Returning extra data to my request in Filter after upgrading to PHP 8.1
In PHP 7.X I was able to send extra data from my filter to the Controller:
My app uses bearer token authentication via this Filter. If the token is valid I return the original request and include the user's id:
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Config\Services;


class AuthFilter implements FilterInterface {

    use ResponseTrait;

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null) {
        if ($request->hasHeader('Authorization')) {

            helper('my_cors_helper');
            $frontendBaseUrl = checkFrontendBaseUrl();

            $token = "";
            $token = str_replace(['Bearer ', 'bearer '], "", $request->header('Authorization')->getValue());
            $userModel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
            $user = $userModel->where('token', $token)->first();
            if (!$user) {
                return Services::response()
                    ->setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $frontendBaseUrl)
                    ->setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS")
                    ->setJSON([ 'message' => "Access denied", "type"=> "ACCESS_DENIDED"])
                    ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

            $userModel->update($user['id'], ['last_activity' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
            $request->user_id = $user['id'];
            return $request;
        } else {
            return Services::response()
                ->setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", $frontendBaseUrl)
                ->setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS")
                ->setJSON([ 'message' => "Access denied", "type"=> "ACCESS_DENIDED"])
                ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface  $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null) {

    }

}

After switching to PHP 8.1, I'm unable to set the user's id:
$request->user_id = $user['id'];

Because "Creation of dynamic property is deprecated in PHP 8.1"
As a quick fix I modified the Codeigniter\HTTP\Request class - I've introduced a public $user_id property.
I don't like modifying a file inside the Vendor folder, because it is not how you should do it.
What is the correct way please?

Are you using the latest version of CI?

No, my version is 4.2.10. Could that be the issue?

Possibly, that's 2 years old.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/6193

Updating the codeigniter to the latest version helped me, but I can still see the warnings in the writeble/debugbar log files. I'm trying to solve it the right way

Looks like that PR was never approved and merged into the code.

One way to don't get deprecation warnings is to extend the the IncomingRequest class:
<?php

namespace App\HTTP;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;

class MyRequest extends IncomingRequest {

    public $user_id;

}

And then set up the custom request in Config\Services.php:
<?php

namespace Config;

use App\HTTP\MyRequest;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\UserAgent;

class Services extends BaseService {

    public static function request(App $config = null, bool $getShared = true) {
        if ($getShared) {
            return static::getSharedInstance('request', $config);
        }

        $uri = static::uri();
        $userAgent = new UserAgent();
        $config = $config ?? config('App');

        return new MyRequest($config, $uri, 'php://input', $userAgent);
    }

}

